# Good text suggest to abstract algebra and point set topology as well as metric space, or you may consider as introductory to topology

Tags: soft-question

I am going to take courses about those topic. i want some text which is suitable for beginner and with some difficult example or questions.

Answer (score 1):

I think that [the book by Hunter and Nachtergaele](http://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/book/pdfbook.html) covers exactly these topics in first chapter and I have found that very well-written, especially if you need an introductory book.

Comment: Thx, its really nice!